# How to add a grouping header when render json:?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, restkit

In the controller:

```
if @topic.save
  render json: @topic, status: :updated, location: @topic
else
  render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

Where there is an error, the json response is like:

```
{"topic_id":["has already been taken"]}
```

How can I add a grouping prefix to the error(s) json response, such that it's easier to be parsed on the client (RestKit) path mapping? e.g.:

```
{"errors":[{"topic_id":["has already been taken"]}]}
```

Comment: how about `render :json => {:errors => @topic.errors}`? You can customize the Hash when do rendering json

Comment: I am doing something similar `{ 'errors' =>  [@topic.errors] }`, but worried whether it's the most _elegant_ way ;-)

Comment: I was looking for something like `self.include_root_in_json = true` but that only affects data, but not errors.